# Only show link if the field has been filled

Tags: php, wordpress, field, href

On the author page of my Wordpress site, I use this code to display the author's twitter URL:

```
<a href=”http://twitter.com/<?php the_author_meta(‘twitter’); ?>” target=”_blank”>Twitter</a>
```

The problem with this code is that it will still display the link even if the user did not fill in the Twitter field in their backend profile. How can I make so that it will only display **if** the user have filled in their twitter?

I would presume a basic PHP IF statement would be the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. You can use `get_the_author_meta` to get the value of that `meta` (not as `the_author_meta` which prints the value).
Then , compare it to `""` (empty string) , and if it's not empty - echo the link,
otherwise...., well we don't have otherwise - it just won't print the link.

```
<?php if(get_the_author_meta('twitter') != ""): ?>
<a href="http://www.twitter.com/<?php the_author_meta('twitter'); ?>" target="_blank">Twitter</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: It did indeed, please update your answer to add the closing </a> tag and I will accept it as correct, thank you very much!

Comment: On a second note, it appears to not work properly. The IF statement works, so if the field is not filled, the link will not appear. However, it does not grab the twitter field once it is filled. Meaning that the **<?php the_author_meta(‘twitter’); ?>** part never returns anything. Is there a typo in your code?

Comment: Updated the code (changed the type of quotes) , try the updated code and update me

Comment: It works fine now, however the url becomes: **http://mydomain.com/"http://twitter.com/username"** The only solution that I can think of is to remove the double quotes in the A tag and it will fix it, do you know of a different solution?

Comment: Updated it again (those weird quotes thing again).

Comment: Wow never thought there where two types of double quotes :) Cheers dude works fine. I have upvoted this and accepted as correct answer.